# Comparing beans with multiple properties, depending on two beans each

Tags: java, mysql, xml, sorting, comparator

I have a problem. First let me show you the structure of the beans I want to be able to compare:

**ItemDTO contains:**

- name
- itemID
- type
- subtype
- bodypart
- price

**ItemOnCharacterDTO contains:**

- ownerID
- itemID
- count
- location

**ItemDTO are** read statically from XML files. There thousands of them and they don't change (at least I don't care if they do at the moment).
**ItemOnCharacterDTOs are** created by querying a database. The ownerID, itemID, count and location vary per character and thus are saved in the database. The itemID here corresponds to a valid ItemDTO.

I have an array (or ArrayList) of ItemOnCharacterDTO-objects which I want to sort by multiple criteria, e.g. by "itemOnCharacterDTO.ownerID", "itemDTO.name", "itemDTO.type".

If I combined ItemDTO and ItemOnCharacterDTO to one class (e.g. ItemAllDTO), I could easily use the [apache BeanComparator](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/commons-beanutils-1.7.0/docs/bean-collections/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html). However: I am not.
The reason is: the user can have multiple items on different characters. The basic item-data (ItemDTO-data) is the same, while user-specific data (ItemOnCharacterDTO-data) changes. Therefore I load the former only once, while loading user-specific data each time I encounter a different ItemOnCharacterDTO.

*Since I'm writing it all in GWT, I decided to sort on the server, because that's where all the information is (in contrast to the front end, where item-related information is loaded with pagination). I'm using Java on server-side. I've written a mapper to properly retrieve the static XML data from the item-related XML-files. But character-based item-related information is stored in a mysql-database*.

**I want to be able to sort the array or ArrayList of ItemOnCharacterDTOs by attributes present in either ItemOnCharacterDTO- or ItemDTO-object** (I have a way to distinguish what DTO the given attribute belongs to - meaning: I know if the user sorts by "count", that I am going to have to check ItemOnCharacterDTO-object for this attribute and not the ItemDTO-object).

Each user might have a few thousand objects. Each ItemOnCharacterDTO has about 5 attributes, but each ItemDTO has about 25 or so. Therefore combining them into one object - even just for comparison purposes - is not really an option as it will be very slow and memory-consuming.

Does someone have a better approach? I'm glad for any help - even if you just give a raw idea. I'll work it out.

Thank you very much in advance! Your help is greatly appreciated!

Igor.

P.s.: if you have any further questions, please feel free to ask - I'll reply as soon as possible!
P.s.2: is there maybe something like "LINQ" for Java? Maybe it'd help me solve my problem?

Comment: I just saw that there's a JXPath, which is able to query objects. Is there a way to use it to compare based on two beans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At that time (**before Java 8**) I had ended up using [JoSQL](http://josql.sourceforge.net/), because I ended up wanting dynamic queries in a way that most (including myself) can easily understand. It let me select, compare, order and limit my result set in various ways - just what I wanted to do back then.

Nowadays one would probably use Java 8 lambda expressions for what I was trying to do back then (select certain items, compare, order, limit the resulting set etc.). I do believe there are other means to interpret data - especially if the amount of data is huge, but back then it was not necessary since the amount of data I was dealing with was not huge enough to e.g. consider reusing some database system instead.

*Edit:* I am in no way affiliated with JoSQL, I was just using it to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create two hash maps and keep the key same in both while objects will be from different lists. This means you can access them easily and match them easily.

You could also override equals and hashcode method in both objects.

You could also then wrap both in one object and use that for sorting.

Comment: I'm afraid that wrapping the objects into one would make me create a deep-copy of the object-data. That's what I'd like to avoid though, because it's ridiculous to copy the data just to sort the items and then discard it - and stay unsure about whether the garbage collector performs well enough. That's why I'd like to keep the data in two different DTOs. I mean: I'm not changing data in ItemDTO. It just contains additional sort criteria (such as name, type, price etc.). So I have to somehow take that information into account when sorting. But I most likely don't have to copy the ItemDTO.

Comment: No you don't need to deep copy. You can store references in the wrapper object. And override equals in the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own comparator that takes into account data from both classes. As a helping structure you can hold 2 maps where key is the DTO id for both DTOs. This way you can find the second DTO by ID for comparison.

Comment: I don't have a problem finding the DTOs - I'd probably just stick them into the comparator-method(s). What I'm unsure about is how to actually write a Comparator or CompareTo-method, that takes into account more than just another object of the same type (e.g. taking the arguments: thisItemDTO, thisItemOnCharacterDTO, anotherItemDTO, anotherItemonCharacterDTO). Do you have any hints? Your approach is the one I'd like to follow, because I don't want to create an object that contains data from both DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are already doing the right thing. comparing by [BeanCompartor](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/commons-beanutils-1.7.0/docs/bean-collections/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html,%22BeanCompartor%22) or your custom comparator should be giving you the capability to compare by navigating the object hierarchy. So, this is right way i believe.

Comment: That's what I thought about .. but it seems that the BeanComparator is supposed to be able to compare two beans of the same type. I don't know how I'd make it take more information into account... except actually assigning the ItemDTO-object to the ItemOnCharacterDTO-"itemID" and connecting it like that in order to access it later using the dot. But that'd make me wrap object data into one object - which I'd like to avoid for performance reasons (I don't need this object data anywhere else - just for sorting.. so copying the data around just for this is a ridiculous performance decrease imo).

Comment: Ok, you can have a cutom caopmartor passed to BeanComparator. That would be an annonymous class implementing Compartor interface. And the logic inside that correctly implemented inside compare method. Have a look at second example here. If you are sating that you can get ItemDAO from the itemId in your ItemCharacterDAO easily then it should not be an issue.

Comment: Sorry missed the link Second example given here : http://www.discursive.com/books/cjcook/reference/beans-sect-comparing

Comment: A performance optimization can be to have those proper classes instead of anonymous if those are getting repeated again and agin. But basically above should solve the first problem of comparison.